# Calculating the standard deviation of a linkedlist elements

Tags: pointers, math, singly-linked-list, standard-deviation

I wanted to calculate the standard deviation of a inked list elements,so I wrote a function to calculate both the average and the sum and then claculate the standard deviation by the formula , but I am getting error " 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."at the line 46 ,

```
sd += ((first->info)-average)*((first->info-average);
```

Why this problem occurs and is there any way to get rid of it ? 
My code is as follows :

```
class Node
{
public:
    int info;
    Node* next;
        int value;
};
class List:public Node
{
    Node *first,*last;
public:
    List()
    {
        first=NULL;
        last=NULL;
    }
    void create();
    void insert();
    void delet();
    void display();
    void search();
    void sum();
    void sd();
};
void List::sd()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"The Linked List Operations Program";
        cout<<"\n==========================================================="<<endl;
    Node *temp=first;
      int sd = 0;
     int length=0;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        length++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
        int sum = 0;
       while (first != NULL) 
    {
     sum += first->info; 
     first = first->next;
    }
   int average;
   average = (sum/length);
   sd += ((first->info)-average)*((first->info-average);
   first=first->next;
   cout<<average;
   cout<<"The standard diviation is  " <<sqrt(sd)/10 ;
   cin.get();
   cin.get();
}
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int m;
    List l;
    Node *first;
    int ch;
    l.sd();
    return 0 ; 
}
void List::create()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"The Linked List Operations Program";
        cout<<"\n==========================================================="<<endl;
    Node *temp;
    temp=new Node;
    int n;
    cout<<"\nEnter an element to create the first node of the linkedlist:";
    cin>>n;
    temp->info=n;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
    {
        first=temp;
        last=first;
    }

    else
    {
        last->next=temp;
        last=temp;
    }
}
void List::insert()
{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"The Linked List Operations Program";
        cout<<"\n==========================================================="<<endl;
    Node *prev,*cur;
    prev=NULL;
    cur=first;
    int count=1,pos,ch,n;
    Node *temp=new Node;
    cout<<endl<<"ADDED";
    system("cls");
    temp->info=rand();
    temp->next=NULL;
    last->next=temp;
    last=temp;  

}
```

Comment: Please share what you discovered when you used a debugger.

Comment: When the program stops in the debugger, look at the variables.Don't just paste the debugger output. This program is small enough that you can step through it line by line. Look at the variables after each step and confirm that they have the values you expect.

Comment: You've provided code that shows `first` being set to NULL, but nothing that shows it being set to any other value (presumably `create()` or `insert()` would do that).  Please provide a [mcve] so that this question can be answered.

Comment: You are setting `first` to its `next` element until it becomes `NULL`. What do you expect when you access it after that? Btw, even if this problem was resolved, this code is far from calculating the standard deviation.

Comment: You should separate the calculation of the standard deviation and average from the data structure that holds the values.  It ought to be able to work with a sequential array, a linked list, or anything else you pass in.

Comment: @duffymo , Do you mean that I should pass the values of the list into an array and then call them for calculating the standard deviation ?

Comment: @duffymo , Thanks a world ! the problem solved with separating the average function from the standard deviation .